# Not able to start the wordpress application again

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner in using WordPress. I have downloaded it from bitnami(5.6 version). Cause I want to use it on localhost. I successfully logged-in on WordPress, create my basic website then I shut-down my machine and then on the next day I want to run my localhost again but it is not running anymore.
I checked http://localhost:8081/wordpress/wp-admin/    But this is also not responding. My os is ubuntu 20.04.[this is what i am seeing at localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajNTi.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are possible way to start the local server on ubuntu.
I am also facing an issue when I start my system.

What I have to do is I need to open terminal and need to execute below two commands to start local server.

open your terminal and give a try to below commands:

`sudo service mysql stop`

`sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Comment: I have no path;-   /opt

Comment: first command executed? if yes, then try to trace the path and update in a command